# How to show error message if no data is found?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me with this code?

```
    function blub() {

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'blups1.php?rid=10',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){

         var name = data[0].name;
         alert('ok = '+name);


    },
    error: alert('nix gefunden')
    });


}
```

In case of success it shows me what I want, but the alert from error always pop up at first. Where do I have to place that error alert so that it will only appear if there is no database?

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure why one would just place the alert statement singularly as the callback. Put the alert in a function:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  alert('nix gefunden');
}
```